# How to print out 3 items, which is connected with 2 input(price and quantiy)

Tags: javascript, jquery

One more problem, please help with printing out 3 spans elements at the same time as checking input. I'm beginner in JQuery.
In general, I have price calculator, which gets price(value in first input) of checked elements, multiplies it by quantity(value in second input) and gives total amount.

**HTML**

```
<li class="price">
  <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="5000"  />
  <input class="price-count" type="number" min="1"  value="1" />
  <span class="price-name">Shirt</span>
  <span class="price-price">5000</span>
  <span class="price-uname">pieces</span>
</li>
<li class="price">
  <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="9000"  />
  <input class="price-count" type="number" min="1"  value="1" />
  <span class="price-name">Trousers</span>
  <span class="price-price">9000</span>
  <span class="price-uname">square meter</span>
</li>
```

....there are 30 LI elements

**JavaScript**

```
    $('.option, .price-count').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;  

        $('.option:checked').each(function() {
            sum += $(this).val() * $(this).next('.price-count').val();
            $('#checked-elements').html($(this).next('.price-name').innerHTML);
        });

        $('#total').html(sum);
    });
```

Please help to print out every checked element with name, quantity and unit of measure, separated by commas and using JQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added code to parse the values of the checked items and print them out as a comma-separated list below the total:

```
 $('.option, .price-count').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var selected = $('<ul></ul>');

        $('.option:checked').each(function() {
            var amount = $(this).val() * $(this).next('.price-count').val();
            sum += amount;
            var li = $(this).closest('li');
            var name = li.find('.price-name').html();
            var qty = li.find('.price-count').val();
            var unit = li.find('.price-uname').html();
            selected.append($('<li>'+ name + ', ' + qty + ', ' + unit + '</li>'));
        });

        $('#total').html(sum);
        $('#selected-items').html(selected);
    });
```

Check out this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/7vtvfofj/2/

Comment: No, I need that only CHECKED items were showed. And only when user clicks the checkbox of input.

Comment: There is no need to `parseInt` the value - when using the multiplication operator an implicit conversion from string to int will happen.

Comment: @ТатьянаЧен did you check the updated jsfiddle?  Only the checked items are printed below the total.  If this is not what you want, can you be more specific?  Maybe provide more of your html?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I had copied some of the HTML wrong and so I was getting some console errors without `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can append a tag to the DOM which reads the `price-name`, `price-count` and `price-uname` elements related to the checkbox and formats them in to a string. Try this:

```
 $('.option:checked').each(function () {
     var amount = $(this).val() * $(this).next('.price-count').val();
     sum += amount;
     $('#checked-elements').html($(this).next('.price-name').innerHTML);
     $('<p />', { 
         text: $(this).siblings('.price-name').text() + ' x ' + $(this).siblings('.price-count').val() + ' ' + $(this).siblings('.price-uname').text()
     }).appendTo($items);
 });
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vtvfofj/3/)